# Pass arguments in @selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, selector

I got error when passing arguments in `@selector` method.

This is my code:

```
-(void) accessoryView : (UITextField*) textField
{

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad )],
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad:textField:)]];


    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad : (UITextField*) txt : (id) sender {

}
```

Comment: You can't pass arbitrary arguments to the action selector; the selector must conform to the format that the bar button item is expecting

Comment: Is there any other way to pass "textField" to "doneWithNumberPad" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of reference variable for your textfield. Declare a global property as textfield. Keep a refernce of currently active textfield and access it in every method as per your requirement.

```
UITextField *activeTextField;

// UITextField Delegates
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
     activeTextField = textField;
}
```

You can use this activeTextField property in your class anywhere.

You need to define your class as delegate of UITextField.

```
self.yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

First: Your selector is wrong. I should be `action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad::)` or renaming your second method to `-(void)doneWithNumberPad : (UITextField*) txt textField: (id) sender`.

BUT Second: You can't send custom, additional parameters with an action method. You should access the text field over a property. In your case you can store the current text field in a property, when the editing in the text fields begin. Your view controller should implement `UITextFieldDelegate` to receive this event.

Comment: I have total of 10 textField and five of them need to call accessoryView. How can I use the above code for this scenario.

Comment: I've extended my post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer